# Scaled Image Scrolling on Html/CSS

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to make a webpage with the content scrolling just like normal, but the background image scrolling slower? for example, the user scrolled 100px. The content will scroll 100px, but the background Image will scroll only scroll 20px or so. Is it possible to do this with Html5 and CSS3? or do I need other language/library such as Java or Flash?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Your search keyword is __parallax scrolling_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah , its possible!

you can do that with  jquery.parallax. Please check out this page:

http://stephband.info/jparallax/

jParallax turns nodes into absolutely positioned layers that move in response to the mouse. Depending on their dimensions these layers move at different rates, in a parallaxy kind of way.

Answer (score 1):

[You should use this jquery plugin](http://lab.victorcoulon.fr/javascript/scrolly/)